# How should i configure the Raspberry Pi 3B+ to display two distinct videos or files on different LCD screens (two to be precise) simultaneously?

Tags: gpio, hdmi

1. raspberry pi 3B+
2. HDMI
3. 2 LCD screens

Comment: Replace it with a RPi42GB as that has significantly better support of multiple displays.

Answer (score 1):

Some LCD displays come with SD Cards and have the ability to play from them.

A YouTube example for the Arduino is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lBLKsSEvWHM) using the ILI9341 from Adafruit.